# Paper request: study that correlates distinctive features with neuronal activation

Tags: phonology, reference-request, neurolinguistics

I remember an fMRI study that came out sometime around last year (maybe even 2014) that showed a correspondence between distinctive features and neuronal activation. I can't for the life of me find it. I can't remember the researchers or the university. Any suggestions? (I hope this this kind of question is appropriate for stackexchange!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this, but it wasn't fMRI. It's direct cortical recording!

http://science.sciencemag.org/content/early/2014/01/29/science.1245994.abstract

Comment: Yes--look at this and other stuff by Edward Chang. I just heard him give a talk at Interspeech, and he presented some remarkable findings! The multi-electrode cortical recordings are now giving us tons of new data at a resolution not afforded by fMRI.